# Return next line of matched search string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following variable in a string

```
some_var = ".... \n
... \n
Hello Subject \n
12:34:56:78:90 \n
... \n"
```

I' m trying to get just the value `123456789`. I tried the following code but gives me next two lines from the line matched.

```
re.search(r'Subject((.*\n){2})', some_var).group()
```

Output of above code:

```
Hello Subject
12:34:56:78:90
```

Expected output:

```
12:34:56:78:90
```

Comment: You want o/p as `1234567890` or `12:34:56:78:90`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what prompted you to choose the pattern you are using, but it looks wrong for extracting that number.  Instead, use this pattern:

```
Subject.*\n(.*?)\n
```

And then access the matched number using `group(1)` which is the first (and only) matched capture group.

```
some_var = ".... \n... \nHello Subject \n12:34:56:78:90 \n... \n"
print re.search(r'Subject.*\n(.*?)\n', some_var).group(1)
```

## Demo

Comment: `123456789` can be a string too. I corrected the question! Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @MKD I updated my answer, which doesn't change much.

Answer (score 1):

A small modification to Tim's answer:

```
some_var = ".... \n... \nHello Subject \n12:34:56:78:90 (0x44) \n... \n"
print re.search(r'Subject.*\n(\S+)', some_var).group(1)
```

**Explanation:** 
`\S+` = gets the first string and avoids `(0x44)`

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/YMTQTI24336)**

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
import re;
some_var = ".... \n... \nHello Subject \n12:34:56:78:90 \n... \n";
# you might want to try \r too if its required with \n
s = re.search('Subject[\ ]*\n([\d:]+)', some_var);
if s:
    print(s.group(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do without a regex at all if you do not need to match `Subject` as a whole word, and if you do not care about the type of symbols you match on the line below the line having `Subject` substring.

Use

```
some_var = ".... \n    ... \n    Hello Subject \n    12:34:56:78:90 \n    ... \n"
lst = some_var.split("\n")              # Split at newline
cnt = len(lst)                          # Get the item count
for idx, line in enumerate(lst):        # Enumerate lst to access index + item
    if "Subject" in line and idx < cnt - 1: # If not at end and line has "Subject"
        print(lst[idx+1].strip())       # Strip from whitespace and print next line
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2qP7mb).